# "Module angular2/src/core/compiler/interfaces not declared as a dependency" when using angular2.api.ts

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm building an app in TypeScript for Angular2.alpha27.

Was trying to get rid of my own forged **angular2.d.ts** definition by using the **angular2.api.ts** from the **node_modules/angular2/ts**. Everything compiles, but I get an error in the browser "*Module angular2/src/core/compiler/interfaces not declared as a dependency*".

On the other hand when I try the definitions from es6 or just main directory of angular2 from node_modules I get plenty of compilation errors.

Main motivation for this is **angular2/forms**, which initially is not supported by definitions obtained from DefinitlyTyped or angular2-seed project.

Comment: Provide more code around the error location for better help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will very soon be solved but for now I've found the following typings file that contains everything I need in addition to the angular2.d.ts file from DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/rolandjitsu/ng2-play/blob/master/src/_typings/custom.d.ts

Ref issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2659

Comment: Thanks, it seems that was an alpha thing ;)